# Is it better to pass a C++ object by reference than by value if it is in RAM?

Tags: c++, memory, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, ram

There is a widespread opinion that in the C++ language it is better to pass an object to a function by reference than by value (thus supposedly reducing the number of copies). But what if this object is located in RAM (not in processor the cache) and the function itself accesses the fields of this object several times. As known, access to RAM is expensive (200-600 cycles), but 64-128 bytes are copied at a time. Wouldn't it be more efficent to pass a small object (up to 128 bytes) by value, allowing the processor to copy it into the cache at a time and then access its fields using the high speed cache memory?

Or maybe the compiler in such a situation independently performs implicit copying to the cache?

Comment: If you doubt, make a benchmark for you specific case and make a decision based on a benchmark result. An example of a small object up to 128 bytes: `struct A { std::vector v_{2'000'000'000}; };`. Will its copy be fast?

Comment: **independently performs implicit copying to the cache** It's rather true. Memory is cached in blocks, not in bytes. Once a member variable is accessed, the whole small object will likely be cached.

Comment: It's not the size of the object; it's the cost of copying it. Imagine a type with a copy constructor that pauses for a second; passing by reference will be much faster than passing by value, regardless of what the cache might or might not do.

Comment: *There is a widespread opinion that in the C++ language it is better to pass an object to a function by reference than by value*. I would not say it is an opinion, in general it is a fact (unless the object is really small).  In the end if it is about perfomance you should always measure (using a profiler) and address the biggest bottleneck (and the can even be the original design of your datastructures).

Comment: This might be fun for you to watch [CppCon 2017: Matt Godbolt “What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSkpMdDe4g4)

Comment: I was going to point out that by-value prevents unexpected changes to an object, but `const &`  gives you the same protection unless the code intentionally breaks the const.

Comment: What happens if your object has a pointer or a member that contains a pointer?  Passing by reference means that you don't need to worry about shallow copy vs. deep copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of the physical memory location, passing a large object by value normally forces it to be passed via stack, which means it needs to be copied there first which takes time. The object needs to be accessed either way. Passing by reference saves this copy step.

Additionally, the following depends on compiler and target machine, but in general the compiler will keep the values in CPU registers if it's accessed multiple times in a close succession. Otherwise, which level of memory the object is located in physically is not something the compiler or the program is in control of.

Comment: Pedantic note: C++ does not necessarily use a stack. Stack is just, by far, the most common implementation for tracking objects with automatic storage duration .